# Delete Operation using ASP.Net MVC and Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and Angular JS. I am performing delete operations using these two technologies but I am getting 404 : page not found error while performing these operation.
My Controller Code:

```
[HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult DeleteBranchMaster(int branchId)
    {
         //Deletion Logic.
    }
```

Angular Code:

```
//Delete Branch Data
$scope.deleteBranchData = function (dataId) {
    $http.delete('/Master/DeleteBranchMaster?branchId=' + dataId);
};
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKIpC.png)

Comment: Is that the correct Url seen in your console 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  // Delete action...
    [HttpPost]
    public string DeleteBranchMaster(string fsBranchId)
    {
         //Add your delete operation logic here... 
         //You can return success/fail string message

            return "Record deleted successfully.";
    }


//add following script...    
var app = angular.module("mvcCRUDApp", []); 
app.controller("mvcCRUDCtrl", function ($scope, crudAJService) {

$scope.deleteBranchData = function (dataId) {
        var getBranchData = crudAJService.DeleteBranchService(dataId);
        getBranchData.then(function (msg) {
            alert(msg.data);            
        }, function () {
            alert('Error while delete operation..!! Try again after sometime..');
        });
    }
});

//this is angularjs service..Service name is crudAJService..
app.service("crudAJService", function ($http) {

    //Delete service.. It will call Master controller's DeleteBranchMaster action.
    this.DeleteBranchService = function (branchId) {
        var response = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "Master/DeleteBranchMaster",
            params: {
                fsBranchId: JSON.stringify(branchId)
            }
        });
        return response;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the controller - action as per shown or use route name to define the id name properly

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteBranchMaster(int id)
{
     //Deletion Logic.
}
```

//Delete Branch Data

```
$scope.deleteBranchData = function (dataId) {
  $http.delete('/Master/DeleteBranchMaster/' + dataId);
};
```

Or

```
[HttpDelete("{branchId}")]
public ActionResult DeleteBranchMaster(int branchId)
{
     //Deletion Logic.
}
```